# yq command is not writing contents to the file persistently

Tags: yaml, yq

I am using yq tool to write data to a yaml file , but i am unable to write the data persistently to the yaml file. when executed the below command it returns the output i have expected to the console but it is writing only first section to the file... any help is greatly appreciated.

yq version: 3.4.1

Command :

```
yq n affinity-controller.fresh_install "False" > history.yaml
yq w -d'*' history.yaml snapshot-validation-webhook.fresh_install "False"
```

contents of history.yaml after executing the above command

```
affinity-controller:
  fresh_install: False
```

expected output :

```
affinity-controller:
  fresh_install: False
snapshot-validation-webhook:
  fresh_install: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For yq v3, according to doc, you should do it like this:

```
yq w -i history.yaml snapshot-validation-webhook.fresh_install "False"
```

For yq v4 (please note the leading dot):

```
yq e '.snapshot-validation-webhook.fresh_install=False' -i history.yaml
```

Tested and verified on localhost.

Snap users: Please note that there's a bug in yq:4.30.7
https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1521

Symptom: You'll get the following error when running yq:
`Error: chown/tmp/temp1636774104: operation not permitted`

Downgrade yq to last working version (4.30.3): `sudo snap refresh yq --channel=v4/stable`